# checking if an address exists inside a struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I was wondering if anyone could help. I'm trying to check to see if an address has been stored in a struct, but the results I'm getting are not what I'm expecting.

So basically I have two functions....one is to store a value, and the other is to check if an address has already used the first function and stored a value.

so if I call `storeValue()` and then I input a value, the value gets stored correctly, but if I then call `checkForAddress()` and input my address, it still shows "false". I'm expecting it to show true because it was the same address I called `storeValue()` with to begin with.

I need to be able to confirm if addresses have already stored values....ultimately it will mean that if they have stored a vlue, then they won't be able to call `storeValue()` any more....they only get one chance to store a value from a single address.

Can anyone help, as I'm not really sure what I've done wrong :-(

thanks

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";



// MAIN CONTRACT

contract DoesAddressExist {
        using SafeMath for uint256;


constructor() public {
}


function () private payable {}



struct ValueRecorded {
    uint valueEntered;
    uint8 flag;
}

ValueRecorded[] public valueRecorded;

mapping(address => ValueRecorded) user;




function storeValue(uint _value) public {
        ValueRecorded memory newValueRecorded = ValueRecorded ({
                valueEntered: _value,
                flag: 1
                });
        valueRecorded.push(newValueRecorded);

}


function checkForAddress(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
    if(user[_address].flag == 1) {
    return true; }
    else return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: your contract might work perfectly but you may have problems in the way you are calling your contract, specify that in an edit.

Comment: I appreciate the response but not sure what you mean by the way that I'm calling it? I'm deploying the contract, then calling storeValue() and inputting a number (e.g.10) as my value.....then calling checkForAddress() and the response still shows false, even though if I were to call valueRecorded() it shows my address and my flag = 1

Comment: what I meant is that to store value you need to send a transaction. to read value you need to call the EMV. if you are doing that right it is probably a problem with your contract code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you're never actually storing something in your `user` mapping, and you're not actually checking it in `storeValue`.

Also, you don't need to keep track of a whole `VoteRecorded`. To accomplish your goal, a `bool` is sufficient:

```
mapping(address => bool) stored;

function storeValue(uint _value) public {
    require(!stored[msg.sender], "Sender already stored a value.");
    stored[msg.sender] = true;

    // ...
}
```